# Derivative of unit normal vector is tangential

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, tangent-bundle

Frankel in his The geometry of physics writes on page 203:

$\mathrm{N}=x_u \times x_v/||x_u\times x_v||$ be the unit normal to $M^2$,
where M is a two dimensional manifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Moreover, he says, 
$$d\mathrm{N}/dt=(\partial N/\partial u^{\alpha})(du^{\alpha}/dt)$$
and this vector is a **tangent** vector to $M^2$ since $\mathrm{N}$ is a *unit*
vector.

My question is, any linear combination of tangent vectors will remain tangent, so why does he mention *since* $\mathrm{N}$ *is a unit vector*;
i.e. where/how does he use the unity of $\mathrm{N}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the expression

$$ \frac{\partial \mathrm N}{\partial u_\alpha} \frac{du_{\alpha}}{dt},$$

$\frac{du_\alpha}{dt}$ is a scalar and $\frac{\partial \mathrm N}{\partial u_\alpha}$ is a vector in $\mathbb R^3$. It is in general not in the tangent plane $T_pM \subset \mathbb R^3$. However, if $\|\mathrm N\|=1$, then

$$ 0 = \partial_t \|\mathrm N\|^2 = 2 \left\langle \mathrm N , \frac{d\mathrm N}{dt}\right\rangle.$$

Thus $\frac{d\mathrm N}{dt}$ is orthogonal to $\mathrm N$ and thus tangent to $M$.

Comment: OK. But how can I imagine a normal (but necessarily non-unit) $\mathrm{N}$ to $M^2$ for which $\frac{\partial \mathrm N}{\partial u_\alpha}$ is *not* tangent to $M$ at $M_p$?

Comment: It is quite easy to give an example: let $M$ be any surface with normal vector $N$. Then the normal vector fields $ N' = fN$ for some nonconstant $f : M\to \mathbb R$ will have non-tangential $\frac{dN'}{dt}$. @user122424

Comment: Is your $fN$ a derivation or a function application? Between what 2 things is formally $N$ a map?

Comment: No, $fN$ is just the pointwisely multiplication: for each $x\in M$, $fN$ at $x$ is just the number $f(x)$ multiplied to the vector $N(x)$ @user122424